# Save data from an Angular 2 component before navigate to another component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, hook, lifecycle

I would like to save some Angular 2 component related data to the database just before navigating from that particular component to another component so that database saved data will be able to display on the second component. In order to do that I called the **save** method on *ngOnDestroy()* hook of the first component and **display** method on second component *ngOnInit()*.

However, It looks like *ngOninit()* calls before ngOnDestroy() completely finished. It means before saving data into the database second component retrieve old data and displaying.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Would it be possible if you push the data in the first component into a shared service between the two components and subscribe to it in your second component's init?

Comment: In my case, only a particular saved item is indirectly required for displaying some processed data in the second component. So having a shared service is not much fit in this scenario. Would it be any other way of synchronize loading the components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `CanDeactivate` for this purpose. The router only continues the route change if a `Promise` returnes from `routerCanDeactivate` resolves to `true`

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=candeactivate

**rc.x**

```
routerCanDeactivate(currTree?: RouteTree, futureTree?: RouteTree) : Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
     ...
  })
}
```

**beta.x or router-deprecated in rc.x**

```
routerCanDeactivate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction)  {
  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
     ...
  })
}
```

The router-deprecated also has `OnDeactivate`. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/OnDeactivate-interface.html. This might be added to the new router as well.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to use 'rxjs/Observable' to return instead of direct Promise.

Comment: Angular only supports `Promise<boolean>` or just `boolean` as return type but you can call `toPromise()` on your observable to get a promise that resolves when the observable is completed. Don't forget to import the `toPromise` operator.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the context of routing and you rely on the (old) router, you could leverage the `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` interfaces rather. Both contain methods that supports promises.

For the `routerOnDeactivate` one, if a promise is returned, the route change will wait until the promise settles.